# Validate dictionary membership with an if statement

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing this code to verify that a user-provided value and key match what I have in my `dict`. When they match, the Welcome portion of the code will run, but if one of them is wrong then it will have to run the `else` statement.

```
name = input("Name: ")
code = input("Code: ")

users = {'rafiki':'12345', 'wanjiru':'12334', 'madalitso':'taxpos'}

if _______ in users: #at this point is where i need your support, yoverify both key and its value at once.
    print ("Welcome back %s " % username)

else:
    print ("Please check if your name or Code are correctly spelled")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
if name in users and users[name] == code:
    print "Welcome back %s" % username
```

Answer (score 1):

In a single operation:

```
if users.get(name) == code:
```

Because `dict.get` return `None` for an unknown key instead of throwing a `KeyError`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if name in users and code == users[name]:
```

Comment: TigerhawkT3 and Jeremy Thanks very much, it works now.